# Issue with $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] when Posting IP's

Tags: php, mysql

So after a lot of testing, I've finally been able to get `$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]` to successfully post the IP into my MySQL Database

**EXCEPT that it doesn't actually
post the right IP. It is only gathering the first 4 numbers and it's not putting periods after the sets of numbers.** (I'm attempting to log IP's when users register accounts )

**What could be the problem and how can I solve it?**

**Here is my Current Code:**

```
<?php 
session_start();

// variable declaration
$username = "";
$email    = "";
$errors = array(); 
$_SESSION['success'] = "";
$ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];


// connect to database
$db = mysqli_connect('host','user','pass','db')
 or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');

// REGISTER USER
if (isset($_POST['reg_user'])) {
    // receive all input values from the form
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['email']);
    $password_1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password_1']);
    $password_2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password_2']);
    $ip = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]);

    // form validation: ensure that the form is correctly filled
    if (empty($username)) { array_push($errors, "Username is required"); }
    if (empty($email)) { array_push($errors, "Email is required"); }
    if (empty($password_1)) { array_push($errors, "Password is required"); }

    if ($password_1 != $password_2) {
        array_push($errors, "The two passwords do not match");
    }

    // register user if there are no errors in the form
    if (count($errors) == 0) {
        $password = md5($password_1);//encrypt the password before saving in the database
        $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password, ip)
                  VALUES('$username', '$email', '$password', '$ip')";
        mysqli_query($db, $query);
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
        header('location: index.php');

        mysql_error();
    }

}

// ... 

// LOGIN USER
if (isset($_POST['login_user'])) {
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);

    if (empty($username)) {
        array_push($errors, "Username is required");
    }
    if (empty($password)) {
        array_push($errors, "Password is required");
    }

    if (count($errors) == 0) {
        $password = md5($password);
        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
        $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
            header('location: index.php');
        }else {
            array_push($errors, "Wrong username/password combination");
        }
    }
}
?>
```

**The code relating to $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];**

```
$ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];

$ip = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]);

        $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password, ip)
                  VALUES('$username', '$email', '$password', '$ip')";
```

Comment: You need to actually show us the "bad" data instead of merely describing it.

Comment: @Sammitch
Sorry, I'm very new to this. I'm not 100% sure what you mean when you say " 'bad' Data" however I took screenshots of my DB Entries and my DB Structure. 

Entries 
https://gyazo.com/4ffad6bbc82cedde11ec85e48f3f6ee7

Structure: 
https://gyazo.com/a71b04dc98fc618d26f3b6c6ed795a23

Comment: @WollyLinka your gyazo links aren't working (at least not on my ipad)

Comment: Remove     $ip = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]);  and see if it works!

Answer (score 4):

You need to make sure that your database table column IP is (var)char of at least 15 characters, for example `VARCHAR(15)`. (Or more than 15 for ipv6)

Also, why do you write `$_POST = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]`, and thus try to overwrite $_POST? Change that into just `$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]`!

Lastly, lookup parameterized queries.